# Crystal report is not working on client PC after installation

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, deployment

I am using Windows 10 64-bit with Visual Studio 2015 and Crystal Reports 13.0.23 with 64-bit runtime.

When I make a setup package on a client computer the program runs but the report produces an error:

> the type initiallizer for "CrystalDecisions.shared sharedUnits " threw
>   a exception.

The Client computer is 64-bit and I installed the Crystal Reports 64-bit runtime.

Answer (score 0):

try installing crystal report 32 bit run time. I guess there is conflict in 32 bit and 64 bit. The 32 bit version is for 64 bit OS. The same fix worked for me.

Comment: as i have used 64  bit while developing can it work on 32 bit?